# C# IndexOf is not working by returns -1 when there is the occurence of string inside another string

Tags: c#, indexof

I've encountered some problem when I try to extract some information from the response message of some device. When I try to get the index of the specific string inside the response message (which is also a string), it returns -1 even the specific string is definitely inside the response message.

Here are the code:

```
string hexMessage = "\u0002\u0004600000000000024000\u001c02\0@APPROVED                                \u001cD0\0iNETS Test Merchant                                                   \u001c16\0\b10050202\u001cD1\0\u001510050202000    \u001c50\0\u0012000000000000\u001cH6\0\u0006123456\u001c40\0\u0012000000000950\u001cZA\0\u0006000050\u001cZB\0\u0006000020\u001cZC\0\u0006000040\u001c30\0\u00161111737910011205\u001cC2\0\b12122025\u001cZP\0\u0006000030\u001c01\0\u0006000006\u001cD2\0\u0010DBS Bank  \u001cZT\0\u00190000000000000000000\u001cD3\0\u0012123456123456\u001cC1\0\u000220\u001cC0\0d0100000000000113112618000100000001999800000001999700000000200003\u001c\u0003(";
string tag = "1c30";

if (hexMessage.Any(c => tag.Contains(c)))
{
   int afterTag = hexMessage.IndexOf(tag); 
   Console.WriteLine("Found!" + afterTag);

   Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Not Found!");
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The `hexMessage` is the response message return by the machine, its very long though I think the length shouldn't affect the IndexOf function.

This piece of code will return result as: `Found! -1`

I've been look through the internet for the problem yet I couldn't found any solution. Please help, thank you.

Comment: `hexMessage.Any()` is treating it as a bunch of `char`s, and seeing if any character in that collection appears in `tag` (which it does)

Comment: Add `@` before the string to avoid escaping \

Comment: @TimSchmelter adding `@` is working thanks! But my hexMessage was a variable pass from another method, how can I add the `@` into the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial condition is incorrect, which means that it enters the `if` block when it shouldn't, leading you to believe that the `IndexOf` is the issue.

Store the result of `IndexOf` first, and then do a check on it.

```
int afterTag = hexMessage.IndexOf(tag);
if (afterTag >= 0)
{        
   Console.WriteLine("Found!" + afterTag);

   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: It is not found the `tag`. From @Tim Schmelter comment I know that adding `@` in front of the string could solve the problem since its escaping the \, may I know how to add `@` into the string variable since the string itself is pass by another method which direct get from the machine? Thanks!